# Using dropbox in fuduntu

Tags: linux, dropbox

I have Fuduntu 2013.1 (Best of Fedora and Ubuntu in one OS) installed on my Gateway netbook, along with a couple of other distros including CrunchBang.

All my distros have a shared /home partition.  I originally thought this was a good idea, but now I see, as 2F4U mentioned (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2051212), that all the config files stored in ~ start to conflict across distros.  But now it is too late to change my usernames or mount it as /stuff (I think.  If this is possible, let me know).

So, my main remaining problem is that Dropbox keeps generating the following error:

```
Starting Dropbox...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dropbox", line 1360, in <module>
    ret = main(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/bin/dropbox", line 1349, in main
    result = commands[argv[i]](argv[i+1:])
  File "/usr/bin/dropbox", line 1220, in start
    if not start_dropbox():
  File "/usr/bin/dropbox", line 716, in start_dropbox
    time.sleep(interval)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

(I pressed Ctrl-C after it generated the zlib error)

I tried updating zlib and python, installing zlibc,zlib1g,and -dev versions (couldn't find any of these), but alas!  Nothing works.

Comment: tried to purge zlib and re-installing?

Comment: Do you mean with yum reinstall zlib?  or do I have to do something like this: http://serverfault.com/questions/41502/yum-equivalent-of-apt-get-purge

Comment: the last option you referred is precisely what i meant.

Comment: Tried uninstalling zlib, but it tries to remove yum, which is protected (for good reason: a package manager should never uninstall itself).  Simply too many things depend on zlib for me to try your method.